# How to supress maven-javadoc-plugin run form parent pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a pom.xml https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.2/miglayout-swing-5.2.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>miglayout-swing</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MiGLayout Swing</name>
    <description>MiGLayout - Java Layout Manager for Swing</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

with this sources https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.2/
And I got the following error:

```
INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  52.475 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-13T14:12:16+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project miglayout-swing: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: 
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
[ERROR] javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module.
```

Please tell me how to completely TURN OFF  maven-javadoc-plugin? I need to build this project without javadoc.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the property `maven.javadoc.skip` to `true`, i.e. in your `<properties>` section add something like

`<maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>`

Comment: Thank you, it works! Could you tell me also how to skip goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign goal ?

Comment: `gpg.skip`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html